# Oracle Query to convert 2000 to 20.00

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number in my oracle database as 4000 , i have to convert it to 20.00 and insert it to another . Please help me how to perform this using oracle query.

Comment: I have a number in my oracle database as 2000 , i have to insert it as 20.00  to another oracle schema. Please help me how to perform this using oracle query.

Answer (score 2):

do you find something below

```
select 4000/200.00 from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to keep a decimal point, it looks as if the target column's datatype is `VARCHAR2` which means that `TO_CHAR` function (along with appropriate format mask) might help. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table source (num number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into source (num)
  2    select 2000 from dual union all
  3    select 400  from dual union all
  4    select 5    from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> create table target (cchar varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into target (cchar)
  2    select to_char(num/100, '999G990D00')
  3    from source;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from target;

CCHAR
--------------------
      20,00
       4,00
       0,05

SQL>
```